Eigen vector restrict rule
Considering that C++ code compiled to x86/64 (GCC 11, -O2) :
    static constexpr int N = 4;
    typedef std::complex<float> cfloat;
    typedef Eigen::Vector<float, N> VectorNf;
    typedef Eigen::Vector<cfloat, N> VectorNz;
    
    void vop5a1 (VectorNf & a, const VectorNz & b)
    {
        a = b.array().abs2();       // No SIMD
    }
    void vop5a2 (VectorNf * __restrict__ a, const VectorNz * __restrict__ b)
    {
        *a = b->array().abs2();     // SIMD if restrict present
    }
    void vop5c (VectorNf & a, const VectorNz & b)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {  // tests restrict then SIMD (2 mulps, 1 addps) else scalar x86
           a[i] = std::norm(b[i]);
        }
    }

The generated x86-64 code for vop5a1 does not use SIMD.
vop5a2 is equivalent with a "C style" API and does generate SIMD instructions.
vop5c code executes a dynamic test of no-overlap between a et b and then has a "then SIMD else scalar" code.
What magic should I add in vop5a1 to enable SIMD coding ?

What instructions output do you get and you expect (also shouldn't change much, but is EIGEN_NO_DEBUG present?) I see it using mulss (and no fork in vop5c) and I can't figure out what  else can be there. In 2nd case you told it that these are distinct locations.

Interesting. It seems like Eigen doesn't have custom code paths for abs2 which is why it is up to the compiler to do the right thing. One indicator for this is also that the vectorized code uses movups even though they are aligned vectors. You can get the first version to vectorize with a = b.array().abs2().eval() but this will perform worse in dynamic vectors where eval forces a new dynamic allocation

Compiling with -DNDEBUG, which implies EIGEN_NO_DEBUG

@Homer512 I think Eigen barely has any vectorization code for cases which requires changes of packet-size (e.g. from complex to real). But I haven't been involved in development for a while.
